# Image with Overlay ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I found a example and it works well, if I remove the `ScrollViewer`, but I need the image inside of the `ScrollViewer`. The `TextBox` shall be a overlay of the image.

In this example the image is not inside the `ScrollViewer`. Could somebody please advise how I go about adding the image inside?

```
<Image Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="/Images/Italien.png"
       Stretch="None"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="123" Foreground="Aqua" Background="Transparent"
                             FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Justify" BorderBrush="Red"
                             BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding Width}"
                             Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your requirements here but you could add both the Image and the ItemsControl to a Panel such as for example a Grid and then add the Panel to the ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid>
        <Image Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="/Images/Italien.png" Stretch="None"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <TextBox Text="123" Foreground="Aqua" Background="Transparent" FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Justify" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

A ScrollViewer can only have a single Child element so in order to be able to add both an Image and some other element to it you need to add both of them to a Panel.

**Edit:** If you want the to set the Image as the background of the Canvas ItemsPanel you could set the Background property of the Canvas to an ImageBrush:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Italien.png" />
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: I forgot to place the Grid, but I have one more issue. the textbox (overlay) has a offset to the image. Can I assign the textbox as child to the image to prevent the offset?

Comment: No, an Image has no Child property but you could adjust the position of the TextBox using its Margin property and/or HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment property. The ItemsControl with the TextBox(es) will end up on top of the Image since they are located in the same Grid. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I get the location for the overlay based on the image pixels and i would like to save the work to recalculate all values to have the correct position of the overlay to match. Is there a easier way?

Comment: So you basically want to set the Image as the background of the Canvas panel then? Then you could just set the Background property of the Canvas in the ItemsPanel to an ImageBrush. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, works. I fixed the height and witdh  of the canvas to the image size, because no image stretch is required. Unfortunally the scrollviewer is not working, but is for the first demo app ok. I found example for my requirement https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20457/Annotating-an-Image-in-WPF but this will take some time to change to mvvm pattern

Comment: Has your issue been solved then? Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if it helped you then. And ask a new question if you have a new issue.