# How can I drop a ListViewItem onto a Canvas and render the image, the Item contains?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a custom object of type "Module", where I store an Image and a Name. These objects are stored in a ListView, where I drag and drop them onto a Canvas, so I can arrange them (Kind of like a puzzle). First, I just drew the Image:

```
var module = e.Data.GetData("MyFormat") as Module;
Canvas CanvasView = sender as Canvas;

Image image = new Image();
image.Source = module.ModuleImage;

Point enterPoint = e.GetPosition(this.moduleCanvas);

Point PointToDraw = new Point(0, 0);
PointToDraw.X = enterPoint.X - DropPosition.X;
PointToDraw.Y = enterPoint.Y - DropPosition.Y;

//+35 and +43 so the Module gets dropped in the way you picked it up
image.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, PointToDraw.X + 35);
image.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, PointToDraw.Y + 43);

CanvasView.Children.Add(image);
```

But then I realized, I need an Object on the canvas, not just an image, so I tried this:

```
ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem();
var module = e.Data.GetData("MyFormat") as Module;
Canvas CanvasView = sender as Canvas;

lvitem.Content = module;
CanvasView.Children.Add(lvitem);
```

But this won't render the Image on the canvas of course. It just tells me `MyNamespace.Module`. How can I make the Canvas render the Image of the object, the ListViewItem contains?

Comment: Make the canvas the itemspanel of an itemscontrol. Bind itemssource to a collection of itemviewmodel. Datetemplate itemviewmodel into whatever you want. Each item is in a container. Bind canvas.left and canvas.top on that to x and y properties in your itemviewmodel. You should be able to find a bunch of examples of how to do this if you google. Pretty sure I've previously posted on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Image` property of your `Module` class returns an actual `Image` element, you could set the `Content` property to this one:

```
lvitem.Content = module.Image;
```

If `Image` returns a path, you could set the `Content` property to a `ContentControl` with a `ContentTemplate` that you may create programmatically using either a `FrameworkElementFactory` or `XamlReader.Parse`. In the `ContentTemplate`, you define the `Image` element:

```
ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
cc.Content = new LongTextConverter();

FrameworkElementFactory frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
frameworkElementFactory.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));
cc.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory };

lvitem.Content = cc;
```

Or use a `ListView` with a `Canvas` as the `ItemsPanel`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462176/7252182) for an example. You could then set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to an `IEnumerable<Module>` and define an `ItemTemplate` that will be applied to each `Module`.

Comment: Well, Module contains an ImageSource, but even if I would do `lvitem.Content = module.Image;` I'd still only have the image on the canvas instead of the whole object

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn: I though that's what you wanted. But you could still use a `ContentPresenter` and a `ContentTemplate` as I also suggested. Obviously the `Canvas` cannot be supposed to know how you want to present a `Module` object without you telling it.

Comment: I want a winforms-like editor, where I can drag and drop objects from a list, reorder them and make them exchange data. Like a puzzle-editor, where the puzzle tells you when you're done

Comment: How is that related to your question "How can I drop a ListViewItem onto a Canvas and render the image, the Item contains?"? I believe it has been answered.

Comment: I need the object on the canvas, but instead of "mynamespace.module", I want the image of the module to be rendered. Not just the image, I need an object behind it. Like a ListView. You have your objects stored in it, but you can chose how to show the Items. Mine has the Image and the name below. but it's still an object, I can use

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn: You should put the `Image` or whatever you want to render in the `ContentTemplate`.